# How to get a Javascript Chained Menu Output Values of Selected Drop Downs after Submitting Form?

Tags: javascript

I am using this script [Dynamic Drive Chained Menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chainedmenu/chainedmenu.html) and what I am trying to do is when someone clicks the "go" button the values of the selections made display in a text box with a message that says something like "You have selected:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the main part, from the `alert` is up to you :)

```
function goListGroup(){
    var options = [];
    for (i=0;i<arguments.length; i++){
        if (arguments[i].selectedIndex!=-1){
            options.push(arguments[i].options[arguments[i].selectedIndex].value);
        }
    }
    alert(options);
}
```

Don't forget to set the `value` attribute on the `option` element!

Comment: FRAGA thanks for the help. This worked great! The only question I have is how do I take the commas out when the alert appears? I get this A,B,C,D,E,F would like for it to be ABCDEF. I apologize for my "rookie-ness" not really a programmer.

Comment: Oh, sure Octavio. You can split it into lines by doing: `alert("You have selected:\n- " + options.toString().replace(/,/g, "\n- "));`

Comment: FRAGA thanks for the help. I took out the breaks "\n" but this helped me figure out how to display them how I wanted. Now I have to start messing around with how to get it to display the same thing that is alerted into a text box. We will see how that goes! I wish I could upvote your answer but it says I need 15 reputation points for that...I will upvote it when I get there.

Comment: no problem. if you've got another issue, post here too, so it'll be easier to reply.

Comment: sounds good. I appreciate your quick responses and taking time to read my comments/questions. I will keep you posted on how my next step goes.

Comment: Okay so I have successfully made the values write to a text box by changing the <code>alert()</code> with <code> document.listmenu0.model.value = (options.toString().replace(/,/g,"")); }</code> However, when I hit the reset button the values stay inside that text box. I know I have to add some code to reset this in the <code>function resetListGroup</code> but don't know how to write it. Finally, how can I pass this value to a text box in a different page after displaying a new button that will take them to that page. Thanks again. (took me a few minutes to figure out this part but busy day)